# tapestry5.3.7 t:grid not working with xmlgregoriancalendar

Tags: grid, tapestry, gregorian-calendar

Imported ejb entity into tapestry project looks like this 
its in "generated sorces (jax-ws)"

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "money", propOrder = {
    "moneyAmount",
    "moneyCurrency",
    "moneyDate",
    "moneyFinishDate",
    "moneyIO",
    "moneyId",
    "moneyName",
    "moneyNextDate",
    "moneyNumber",
    "moneyPurpose",
    "moneyRenewal",
    "moneyTs"
})
public class Money {
    protected Double moneyAmount;
    protected String moneyCurrency;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar moneyDate;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar moneyFinishDate;
    protected MoneyIO moneyIO;
    protected Integer moneyId;
    protected String moneyName;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar moneyNextDate;
    protected Integer moneyNumber;
    protected String moneyPurpose;
    protected MoneyNextTimeType moneyRenewal;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar moneyTs;

    // Getters and Setters for above
    ...
}
```

all XMLGregorianCalendar is Date in ejb module

In  tapestry page class:

```java
@ejb
statefullEjbMoney

@Persist
@Property
List<Money> mylist

void onPrepareForRender() {
  mylist=statefullEjbMoney.findAll();
}
```

In my template I have:

```html
 <table t:type="grid" t:source="mylist"
                   t:rowsPerPage="10" t:pagerPosition="both"
                   t:exclude="moneyId,moneyIO,moneyNextDate,moneyFinishDate,cliClientId"
                   t:reorder="moneyName,moneyPurpose,moneyAmount,moneyCurrency,moneyDate">
                [Grid here]
            </table>
```

The stacktrace in the glassfish log is:

```
Render queue error in SetupRender[Expenses:grid.columns]: Bean editor model for logic.ws.Money does not contain a property named 'moneyDate'.
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Bean editor model for logic.ws.Money does not contain a property named 'moneyDate'. [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.tml, line 6]
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.util.UnknownValueException: Bean editor model for logic.ws.Money does not contain a property named 'moneyDate'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.beaneditor.BeanModelImpl.get(BeanModelImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.beaneditor.BeanModelImpl.reorder(BeanModelImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.beaneditor.BeanModelUtils.reorder(BeanModelUtils.java:107)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.beaneditor.BeanModelUtils.modify(BeanModelUtils.java:51)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Grid.getDataModel(Grid.java:523)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridColumns.setupRender(GridColumns.java:112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridColumns.setupRender(GridColumns.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$SetupRenderPhase.invokeComponent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:179)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:138)
    ... 84 more
```

If anyone has an idea what is wrong please share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says the Bean Editor Model doesn't have a property called `moneyDate`, which I've always thought was a bit unclear.

To explain, Tapestry doesn't know what an `XMLGregorianCalendar` is, so when Tapestry creates the Bean Model for your grid, it helpfully ignores it.

### Quick Solution

The quick way to solve this is to provide getters on your `Money` entity that return standard JDK `Calendar`s, and display these properties in your grid.

So in your entity:

```java
public class Money {
  @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
  protected XMLGregorianCalendar moneyDate;

  public Calendar getMoneyDataCalendar() {
    return moneyDate.toGregorianCalendar();
  }
  ...
}
```

Then use it in your grid:

```html
<table t:type="grid" t:source="mylist" t:rowsPerPage="10" t:pagerPosition="both"
  t:exclude="moneyId,moneyIO,moneyNextDate,moneyFinishDate,cliClientId"
  t:reorder="moneyName,moneyPurpose,moneyAmount,moneyCurrency,moneyDateCalendar">

  [Grid here] Note 'moneyDate' changed to 'moneyDateCalendar' above [/Grid here]

</table>
```

### Long Solution

If you plan to display lots of `XMLGregorianCalendar`s then the (more involved) solution is to tell Tapestry about XMLGregorianCalendars and how to display them.

First tell Tapestry to add `XMLGregorianCalendar` to the Bean Model by adding this to your Module class:

```java
@Contribute(DefaultDataTypeAnalyzer.class)
public static void contributeDefaultDataTypeAnalyzer(MappedConfiguration<Class<?>, String> config) {
  config.add(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, "xmlGregorianCalendar");
}
```

Now tell Tapestry how to display the new `"xmlGregorianCalendar"`. Add to your Module class:

```java
@Contribute(BeanBlockSource.class)
public static void contributeDisplayBlocksForGrid(Configuration<BeanBlockContribution> config) {
  config.add(new DisplayBlockContribution("xmlGregorianCalendar", "DisplayBlocks", "xmlGregorianCalendar"));
}
```

You now have to create a page called `DisplayBlocks` with a component with an id `xmlGregorianCalendar`:

```java
public class DisplayBlocks {

  @Inject
  private Locale locale;

  @Property
  @Environmental
  private PropertyOutputContext context;

  private final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);

  public DateFormat getDateFormat(){
    return dateFormat;
  }

  public Date getCalendarDate() {
    XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = (XMLGregorianCalendar) context.getPropertyValue();        
    if (calendar == null)
        return null;        
    return calendar.getTime();
  }
}
```

```html
<t:container xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">

  <t:block id="xmlGregorianCalendar">
    <t:output value="calendarDate" format="dateFormat"/>
  </t:block>

</t:container>
```

For more info look at the Tapestry source code and see how Tapestry configures itself. In particular look at:

```
org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.contributeDefaultDataTypeAnalyzer()    
org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.provideDefaultBeanBlocks()
org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.pages.PropertyDisplayBlocks
```

Comment: only date does not have sort button

Comment: I have the same Problem, only on a java.lang.Long field.
Guess the must be another reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There are minimal changes I have made to make it work

description is below.

Appmodule.java added following methods

```java
public static void contributeDefaultDataTypeAnalyzer(MappedConfiguration<Class<?>, String> config) {
    config.add(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, "XMLGregorianCalendar");
}

@Contribute(BeanBlockSource.class)
public static void contributeDisplayBlocksForGrid(Configuration<BeanBlockContribution> config) {
    config.add(new DisplayBlockContribution("XMLGregorianCalendar", "DisplayBlocks", "XMLGregorianCalendar"));
}
```

no @Contribute on method contributeDefaultDataTypeAnalyzer

DisplayBlocks.java

```java
public class DisplayBlocks {

    @Inject
    private Locale locale;
    @Property
    @Environmental
    private PropertyOutputContext context;
    private final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);

    public DateFormat getDateFormat() {
        return dateFormat;
    }

    public Date getCalendarDate() {
        XMLGregorianCalendar date = (XMLGregorianCalendar) context.getPropertyValue();
        Calendar calendar = date.toGregorianCalendar();
        if (calendar == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

XMLGregorianCalendar to  context.getPropertyValue(); 
Than to Calender

DisplayBlocks.tml

```html
<t:container xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">

    <t:block id="XMLGregorianCalendar">
        <t:output value="calendarDate" format="dateFormat"/>
    </t:block>

</t:container>
```

Changed block id to XMLGregorianCalendar

Comment: That's cool - I wrote the answer from the top of my head, straight into StackOverflow. I'm pleased it was clear enough for you to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error like this and reached this page. As it is clear from the error you should easily add a public getter for your property.